# UICollectionViewCell doesn't have the right size

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I'm currently trying to create a `UICollectionView` where all the different cells have the same size by using the following code:

```
let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 20.0)
let itemsPerRow = 2

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * CGFloat(itemsPerRow + 1)
        let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / CGFloat(itemsPerRow)

        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    }
```

For some reason unfortunately my `UIColletionViewCell` don't have the same size.

Here's an image that shows both my `HexagonCollectionViewCell` and my `ImageCollectionViewCell`, both of these `UICollectionViewCells` are using LayoutConstraints:

[image: Screenshot]

And weirdly enough the two plus cells don't seem to be able to stay in one row...

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Are you setting this up via storyboard or programatically?  I've had issues with conflicts and a need to use .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and then things behave as expected.

Comment: I have the collectionview in a storyboard, but I’m creating the hexagon view programmatically as this was easier for me than using the autolayout function in the storyboard. In the HexagonCollection everything but the contentview has .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraint = false.